# Why redeploying JSLINK file adds a ctag to it

Tags: 2013

I deployed a JSLINK file using a feature for 2 lists, using same render method, then I made changes to file by adding 2 new methods and removing 1 method already there.

Now when i go to my list I get this error in console,

> GET
>   https://portal2.ColumnianMarch.com/Sites/01/scripts/crouchlistview.js?ctag=0$$15.0.4569.1000
>   404 (NOT FOUND)

cleared browser cache but it same error.

Comment: How have you deployed your jslink file? SharePoint adds the ctag parameter itself so ensure that browser caching is always taking the most recent copy. Because I see ctag=0 in your query, I think your jslink is not deployed correctly. Somehow it is statically referring to ctag=0 instead of dynamically populating ctag with the most recent version number.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not cleared cache properly,

many people including me have issue with the js files cached because of "ctag" .

Try to clear browser cache properly and restart browser.